Could someone assist with resolving an issue related to the checkout agreement?
The checkout agreement is enable for multi site but its giving the error Error: Call to a member function isSetFlag() on null in /var/www/projects/cei-shop/vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/Checkout/Plugin/Validation.php:119
Stack trace:
can anyone help me to solve this issue
on check agreement field at checkout the order place successfully
